# Android Studio Notification: use Android.support.v4.app or v7?

Tags: android, android-studio, backwards-compatibility

I'm building my first notification using some code from the developer site:

```
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat; //added by Android Studio
[...]
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
   .setContentTitle("My notification")
   .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

But when I do, Android Studio throws an error:

```
required: android.support.v7.app.notificationCombat.Builder
found:    android.support.v4.app.notificationCombat.Builder
```

It seems like the solutions all revolve around whether or not I want to specify v4 or v7 for this. I don't have v4 imported, so I'm assuming that's native? Otherwise I'm not sure why it says it found v4 when they are both spelled exactly the same. From what I understand, the package gives backwards compatibility support, so will v7 always be better?

Target sdk is 23 and minimum sdk: 16

Comment: What do you have imported in your `grade`?

Comment: Just change `android.support.v7.app.notificationCombat.Builder` to `android.support.v4.app.notificationCombat.Builder ` in import statement, buddy. They are same, but if you need more notification feature, use v7.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `NotificationCompat.Builder` before creating the `object`.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay)
                        .setContentTitle("Works!")
                        .setContentText("Works!");
```

Answer (score 0):

V7 is now deprecated and v4 is recommended as the replacement.